# How can I ensure that an overridden method is synchronized

Tags: java, class, synchronization, thread-safety, synchronize

I have a class of common code that is thread safe.

One of the methods in that class is abstract and needs to be overridden for different implementations.

I need to ensure or at least flag to other developers that all implementations of this method need to be thread-safe.

What is the best way to do this?

Is there a keyword or annotation to this effect?

I have already tried `abstract synchronized` but that combination of keywords is not allowed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't do it directly. One thing you can do is have the method be concrete, but invoke an abstract method:

```
public synchronized final void foo() {
    doFoo();
}
protected abstract void doFoo();
```

That way, doFoo() will always* be invoked under the synchronization established by foo().

* unless someone invokes it directly, so you should name and document it to make it clear that they shouldn't.

Comment: Slight refinement: make the public method final.

Comment: Perfect. I don't know why I didn't of that, so simple.

Answer (score 1):

From [Synchronized method in subclass](http://www.coderanch.com/t/240527/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Synchronized-method-subclass)

> Synchronized is the implemenation detail of a method. 
>   You can override a sync method with a method without declaring that as sync and vice versa. 
>   The same holds true for the overloading also.

You can also have a look at, [A synchronized method in the superclass acquires the same lock as one in the subclass.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625726/java-a-synchronized-method-in-the-superclass-acquires-the-same-lock-as-one-in-t)

Answer (score 0):

[This link to the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3) confirms that we can't mix abstract and synchronized.

Though much weaker than a keyword or standard annotation, but stronger than documentation: perhaps try a [Marker interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern)?

> ... provides a means to associate metadata with a class where the
>   language does not have explicit support for such metadata.

This is a stretch, but might help, in that the derived class makes a declaration (**edit**: new example tests the declaration):

```
interface EatMethodIsThreadSafe {}

abstract class Animal {
    public Animal() {
        if (! (this instanceof EatMethodIsThreadSafe)) { 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("eat method must be thread safe");
        }
    }
    public abstract void eat();
}

public class Bear extends Animal implements EatMethodIsThreadSafe {
    public synchronized void eat() {}
    public static void main(String...args) { Bear b = new Bear(); } 
}
```