# Overriding synchronized methods in Java

Tags: java, overriding, synchronized

Let's say I have a synchronized method on some class:

```
abstract class Foo {
    public synchronized void foo() {  // synchronized!
        // ...
    };
}
```

and I overrode it **without** using the synchronized modifier:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public void foo() {               // NOT synchronized!
        super.foo();
        // ...
    }
 }
```

I have a couple of specific question regarding this scenario:

1. Will the overridden method be implicitly synchronized as well?
2. If not, will the `super`-call be synchronized?
3. If there is no `super`-call, will anything be synchronized?
4. Is there a way to force an overriding method to use `synchronized` (I noticed that abstract method definitions or method definitions inside an interface don't allow the synchronized keyword)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684850/how-can-i-ensure-that-an-overridden-method-is-synchronized

Comment: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4294756 Synchronized is not part of the method signature, but part of the method implementation.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
public synchronized void foo() {  // synchronized!
    // ...
};
```

Is essentially the same as:

```
public void foo() {
    synchronized (this) {  // synchronized!
        // ...
    }
};
```

The latter is more explicit, so I would generally suggest using that form. Or better using a lock that is a private field instead of the "outer" object.

So: 1. No. 2. Yes. 3. No. 4. Mark the method `final` and call a `protected` method that may be overridden.

```
public final void foo() {
    synchronized (this) {
        fooImpl();
    }
};
protected void fooImpl() {
    // ...
}
```

As ever, you may well be better off with delegation rather than subclassing.

Comment: using fooImpl is the correct way and still reminds me [ClassLoader.loadClassInternal](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4670071) Of course one can cheat in fooImpl via `monitorExit` / `moniorEnter`

Comment: @bestss Even if you write your own bytecode, monitor enter/exit should be matched. (IIRC there's some peculiar leeway in the spec, but not any reasonable implementation.) Although `fooImpl` could `wait`.

Comment: Unless it's rather new change (and you mean within the same method) it was not the case, even the biased locking had to take consideration of imbalanced enter/exit. If you call `wait` you'd need another thread to execute the code. Otherwise it's just calling in loop monitorExit till IllegalMonitorStateException and counting and then monitorEnter. Hmm, really have to check the spec.

Comment: Found it: [Structured locking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.10) which is non-mandatory. It appears the term is coined w/ java se7 or at least could not find previous references.

Answer (score 23):

Failing to use synchronized when overriding a synchronized method has the potential for causing runtime bugs.  As a safeguard, there is an Eclipse checker you can turn on to detect this condition.
The default is "ignore". "Warning" is also a valid choice.
[image: preferences]

which will produce this message:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Old answer, but you should explain your assertion that failing to synchronize an override can cause bugs.  Explaining how to flag these in a development environment is interesting, but not an answer (to any question, let alone the OP's 4).